# Reloading agnularjs app htaccess issue

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess

I'm trying to set `.htaccess` file so after reload it will first load index.html and then change route so my routing will notice it.

I added

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

to angularjs `.config`

and my htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

the bahoviour is that my spa when I load index.html is working correctly but then when I navigate to some route and press refresh it say:

> Cannot GET /mailbox

What's wrong with my htaccess file? It's in root directory of project.

I'm running my project by live-server.

Comment: do you have `<base href="/">` in your html?

Comment: yes i do have base in html, before title in index.html